# How to silent install an exe file without the /s switch

Tags: c#, automation, extract, silent-installer

I’m trying to automate an installation for an exe file, I can’t use any tools. Already tried /s, extracting the files, and using visual studio.

My company developed two install shield apps that I’m trying to make an automated installation to, I’m having trouble with one.

Neither apps have switches, I tried /s /qn /silent /verysilent , none worked.

I found a solution for the first app, I used - filepath.exe /s/x /b”C:/NewLocation” /v”/qn” , which transformed the exe file into an msi and then I used the msi to silent install, but this doesn’t work on the second exe file.

I tried these:

-looking for switches (filepath.exe /?),  it has none.

-extracting the files in the exe w 7zip, there’s two Msi’s in it but both of them don’t include the whole installation.

-using visual studio (c#) and starting a process, with createNoWindow=true n

The main issue is that my company works on a separate network which is not connected to the internet, so I can’t use any tools from it.

Is there any command/code or any way to automate this installation?

Comment: Sounds weird? If "My company developed two install shield apps" is true then why not simply change the way install shield creates it and implement a silent install? Why the afterworks of unpacking the installer you should have all the parts before already as its your app?

Comment: I’m almost certain It’s not possible, because this app was developed 15-20 years ago

Comment: You don't have the tool chain creating the installer anymore just the compiled installer?

Comment: Exactly (sorry for not being clear enough, English isn’t my first language :)